# Is it possible to change the position of file/folder icons in details view?

Tags: windows, icons, user-folders

In Windows, when folders are in "details view," all file/folder icons are on the left side, regardless of how columns are arranged.  I was wondering if there's any way to move the icons so that they're under a given column (for example, always right next to the file name).  I'm open to programmatic solutions, registry-editing solutions, etc. Thanks for any input.

Comment: *flush with a given column*... I'm uncertain what this means. Do you perhaps mean *adjacent to a given column*?

Comment: Windows 10??????

Comment: I changed "flush" to "under."  And my question applies to any version of Windows.